# An error occurred loading a configuration file: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When I try to build my website project I get the above error, my workstation has 2GB of RAM,Project was being built fine until today.Any Ideas what went wrong.

Comment: Immposible to help without more information, but as a first step I suggest you read DEEP into the exception trace.

Comment: Could you post up the stack/trace?

Comment: Thanks all,in my web solution i have gigabytes of images,flash files folder  i just temporary hide all files in those large folders this vanished the above error

Comment: Restart VS and build again. Probably a plugin acting like it owns the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide large files,massive collections of images etc.  in solution or temporary exclude from project